# as2 dynamically change flash movie clip colour onRollover

Tags: actionscript-2

Hi I have a flash map of the world 
    onRollover a region changes color 
    onRollout changes back no probs 
BUT
I dont want to tween these as my flash file is massive

Can any point me to a tutorial or have any ideas at all.

I cannot do buttons as i need smooth transition also between rollover and rollout.

I have trawled the net and have found nothing to help me in as2.

I really would appreciate any help at all  -  miss_j2000

Answer (score 0):

To do tweening programatically in AS2, you use the `Tween` class. There's a [good tutorial on Kirupa](http://www.kirupa.com/developer/actionscript/tween.htm) on how to use it.

Comment: cool thank you so much - i will have a go tonight (weekend disaster trying to find a solution) best regards to you

Comment: Feel free to post additional, more specific, questions if you have them. (And don't forget to accept answers you feel are sufficient to close the question.)

Comment: Hi see my 2 answer above - i cannot use tweening and not sure how i can change color with this as far as i am aware this moves stuff around from centre point only with different styles of ease, bounce, etc